# array_unique() change between 7.1 and 7.2

Tags: php

According to the [PHP 7.2 backward incompatible changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php) (emphasis mine):

> While array_unique() with SORT_STRING formerly copied the array and removed non-unique elements (without packing the array afterwards), now a new array is built by adding the unique elements. **This can result in different numeric indexes.**

But I wasn't able to write an example where `array_unique` produces a different result in PHP 7.1 and PHP 7.2:

```
ARRAY="[1,'2',1,2,'1']"
echo "var_dump(array_unique(${ARRAY}, SORT_STRING));" | 
     sudo docker run --rm -i php:7.1-cli > 7.1
echo "var_dump(array_unique(${ARRAY}, SORT_STRING));" | 
     sudo docker run --rm -i php:7.2-cli > 7.2
diff -s 7.?
Files 7.1 and 7.2 are identical
```

For what it worth, I'm running PHP in Docker containers on Linux.

Comment: _This can_ doesn't mean will.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Do you think this is a way to say _"we cannot guarantee it will produce the same result"_?

Comment: Yes.  I played with it a little here https://3v4l.org/ and couldn't get a difference.

Comment: It's weird given that `array_unique` claims "Note that keys are preserved". It's not obvious how something can be preserved and then may be not.

Comment: @zerkms It's been a long time since I've worked with PHP, so it is a random thought. But could this be related to associative arrays?

Comment: @zerkms: I think it means given `[5=>0, 6=>0]` in one it might return `[5=>0]` and the other maybe `[6=>0]`. So keys are preserved just which one is eliminated is different.

Comment: It comes without further clarification - it makes an impression that it preserves either :shrug:.

Comment: @AbraCadaver oh right, makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to observe any changes directly after `array_unique`; the element that gets preserved and its index are well defined, and therefore did not change.

But the internal state of the result array is slightly different in 7.1 and 7.2. In this case the 'highest ever used' numeric key is different. This will result in different arrays once you add more elements.

Here is a simple example:

```
$a = [0,0];
$b = array_unique($a);
$b[] = 1;
var_dump($b);
```

Results on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/TOqQ8).

In PHP 7.1 and before the key 1 did exist in $b, and was removed during the `array_unique` call. The next free key is 2.

In PHP 7.2+ the key 1 never existed and will be used for `$b[] = 1`.